# Ubuntu installation on USB

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

I have a 8GB pendrive which i want to use as my HDD
I want the Ubuntu 14.04 to be installed on USB and i want possibility to save files on the USB, update the system and so on...

I was thinking about putting the ISO on USB and use the persistent option, but from what i heard its not safe, because if i boot from USB there will be no login option etc.

So how can i do this?

And second thing is if i would install ATI driver into USB, will I be able to boot the usb on different computer?

Thx

Comment: See [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator) for how to install Ubuntu to a USB drive. Unless you set the ATI driver to specifically load, Ubuntu should be able to choose the right driver for each computer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a Full install to flash.
Unplug/disable your internal drive, plug in your flash drive and install to it using Live DVD or Live USB.
I make the first partition FAT32 or NTFS so I can also use the flash drive for data on a windows machine.

Here is the long version step by step for 12.04:

Turn off and unplug the computer. (See note at bottom)
Remove the side from the case.
Unplug the power cable from the hard drive.
Plug the computer back in.
Insert the flash drive.
Insert the Live CD or Live USB.
Start the computer, the CD/USB should boot.
Select language
Select install Ubuntu.
Select Download updates while installing and Select Install this third-party software.
Continue
At "Installation type" select "Something else".
Continue
Confirm Device is correct.
Select "New Partition Table" 
Click Continue on the drop down.

(Optional partition for use on Windows machine)
Click "Free space" and "Add".
Select "Primary".
Make "New partition size..." about 1000 megabytes.
Location = Beginning.
"Use as:" = "FAT32 file system".
And "Mount point" = /windows.
Select "OK"

Click "free space" and then "Add".
Select "Primary", "New partition size ..." = 4000 to 6000 megabytes, Beginning, Ext4, and Mount point = "/" then OK.

(Optional home partition)
Click "free space" and then "Add".
Select "Primary", "New partition size ..." = 1000 to 4000 megabytes, Beginning, Ext2, and Mount point = "/home" then OK.

(Optional swap space, allows hibernation)
Click "free space" and then "Add".
Select "Primary", "New partition size ..." = remaining space, (1000 to 2000 megabytes, or same size as RAM), Beginning and "Use as" = "swap area" then OK.

(Important)
Confirm "Device for boot loader installation" points to the USB drive. Default should be ok if HDD was unplugged.

Click "Install Now".
Select your location.
Continue.
Select Keyboard layout.
Continue.
Insert your name, username, password, computer name and select if you want to log in automatically or require a password.
Selecting "Encrypt my home folder" is a good option if you are worried about loosing your USB drive.
Select Continue.

Wait until install is complete.
Turn off computer and plug in the HDD.
Stick the side panel back on.

Note:
You may omit disabling the hard drive if, when partitioning you choose to install grub to the root of the usb drive you are installing Ubuntu to, (ie sdb not sdb1). Be cautious, many people have overwritten the HDD MBR.
You can revise grub later, if you wish.

Edit:
If you install ATI drivers to your Full install flash drive it should boot on computers using ATI graphics, but not on computers using Intel or Nvidia graphics.
You can not install graphics drivers to a persistent flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at MKUSB; [MKUSB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

Check out the section on persistent drives. I installed an operating system on an SD card and use it for rescue.

I found it more reliable than other methods of getting an operating system onto usbs/SD cards.